# Problemas de autenticación al clonar repo remoto en GIT (no pide credenciales)

Tags: git

Resulta que intenté hacer un `git clone`, pero equivoqué las credenciales en el momento en que se solicitaban, el cuento es que ahora ya no se pide la autenticación, simplemente la consola saca el mensaje de fatal:

> Authentication failed for ''...

¿Como puedo hacer para que me solicite las credenciales nuevamente? En mi ignorancia he desinstalado, tirado comandos para borrar el *user local*, desisntalado una vez más, pero sigo atascado en esto.

De antemano, gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: puedes comenzar chequeando la documentación de git  en este apartado (https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Empezando-Configurando-Git-por-primera-vez)

Comment: estas intentando esto por consola o mediante algun programa como github desktop o samrt git?

Comment: Saludos, estoy trabajando por consola... Pero ya encontré la solución, se trata de borrar las credenciales por el administrador de credenciales de windows (Panel de control/Adm credenciales.. bla bla). Gracias por prestarle atención al asunto.